# Using <xsl:sort> to sort complex XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use  to sort nodes based on a particular element that can be at any lower level within the XML tree.

Say I have the following XML structure:

```
<Concepts>
<Concept>
    <Type>C</Type>
</Concept>

<Concept>
    <Type>A</Type>
</Concept>

<Concept>
    <OR>
        <Type>B</Type>
    </OR>
    <OR>
        <Type>B</Type>
    </OR>
</Concept>
</Concepts>
```

Note that any `<Type>` within a `<Concept>` will be of the same value, as in the case of `<Type>B</Type>`.

I tried to use the following XSLT1.0 code, but to no avail:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="Concepts/Concept">
            <xsl:sort select="//Type"/>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

The resulting output is:

- C
- A
- B B

and I was hoping for:

- A
- B B
- C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.//Type` to have a path relative to and searching the subtree of the Concept.

Comment: Or better, `(.//Type)[1]` to make it clear you want the first Type. If you don't do this, your code will fail when you move to 2.0.